# How to get data with requests while setting headers and JSESSIONID

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to requests data from a federal agency in germany. I first have to send a post request on an HTML-form and afterwards request an URL with a CSV-Download.
After opening a Requests.Session(), sending the POST-request works with no problems, I have to set a header with the user-agent though.

When afterwards trying to get the CSV with requests.get I need to supply the header again (or I will be blocked) as well as the JSESSIONID for the website to know, which data I am requesting (from filling in the HTML form earlier).

The problem I'm facing is, that on my GET-request when I set the header with the user-agent, my JSESSIONID changes. When I'm not setting the header, the JSESSIONID remains the same, but I'm getting blocked for not providing a User-Agent.

What problem am I facing/What am I doing wrong?

As you can test, when removing the `headers=headers` from the line `r2 = s.get(csv_url, headers=headers)` the JSESSIONID is the same. But without the headers the website blocks my request.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'}

api_url = "https://foerderportal.bund.de/"
url_post = api_url + "foekat/jsp/SucheAction.do?actionMode=searchlist"
csv_url = api_url + "foekat/jsp/SucheAction.do?actionMode=print&amp;presentationType=csv"

# Sending the HTML form
payload  = {"suche.bundeslandSuche[0]": "Hessen"}
r = s.post(url_post, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(s.cookies)

# Requesting the CSV
r2 = s.get(csv_url, headers=headers)
print(s.cookies)


# Writing the file
with open("test.csv", "w") as file:
    file.write(r2.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default user agent is python-requests/{version}

Some websites block access from non web browser User Agents to prevent scraping.

You can define a default user-agent for your session like this:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'

api_url = "https://foerderportal.bund.de/"
url_post = api_url + "foekat/jsp/SucheAction.do?actionMode=searchlist"
csv_url = api_url + "foekat/jsp/SucheAction.do?actionMode=print&amp;presentationType=csv"

# Sending the HTML form
payload  = {"suche.bundeslandSuche[0]": "Hessen"}
r = s.post(url_post, data=payload)

print(s.cookies)

# Requesting the CSV
r2 = s.get(csv_url)
print(s.cookies)
```

Comment: thanks, that solved it. didn't knew i had to assign the headers directly to the session.